# ReactRouter doesn't have a Router property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to integrate React-Router into my project (I'm new to React so bear with me), and I keep getting an error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'type.toUpperCase')`. I'm including a script tag with the CDN/global build in my index.html since I have not had luck with the other methods. My JS code looks like this:

```
var ReactRouter = window.ReactRouter
var Router = ReactRouter.Router
var Route = ReactRouter.Route
var Link = ReactRouter.Link

/* LoginBox && NavBar also defined here */

const LoginPage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div class="LoginPage">
                <NavBar />
                <LoginBox />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'))
```

However, I've read this is generally a typing issue, and I noticed that Router is undefined (and indeed, ReactRouter has no Router property. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of `react-router` are you using? I suspect you're trying to use the `1.x` API, which is only a RC at this point.

Comment: Using react 0.13.3 and react-router 0.13.3, I get this error :/

Comment: your code looks like you are trying to use React Router 1.0, easy to spot by the `component` property in `<Route>`. React Router 0.13 does not use `component` property but instead it uses `handler`. [Here](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/0.13.x/docs/guides/overview.md#with-react-router) is the link to the 0.13.x documentation

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this! COnfusing since this is straight from the documentation, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to version 1.0.0-rc1 solved the problem for me (was 0.13.3). The api has changed and here is the [0.13 api doc](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/tree/57543eb41ce45b994a29792d77c86cc10b51eac9)